# How to detach Screen session with a command with Python Fabric

Tags: python, gnu-screen, fabric

I know about `Ctrl` `A` and `D` combination. What actually I am looking that I am running a long process with `screen`. I want to programatically come out of it as I am using `Fabric` to automate my activities. If I get into command `screen time python3 file.py 1000 2000 5`from [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), it does work but how do I come out of it?

Comment: `tmux` is much easier to automate than `screen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you wouldn't detach from screen - you would not attach yourself in the first place.

From [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3852347/69683):

```
-d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but
        doesn't  attach  to  it.  This  is  useful  for  system startup
        scripts.
```

Comment: For some weird reason it's not working anymore.